# What's this type of recursion called and how do I implement it in JavaScript (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I know how to extract the values of all `href` attributes (of anchor tags) using [`cheerio`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) from a `responseText` string obtained using [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) (or [`https`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html)) then create a flat object of (unique) URLs.

What I don't understand is how would I create a nested object (of nested objects) using recursion (without manually writing each loop).

This `nested` object is of a certain depth (conveniently specified using an argument called `depth`).

For example, let's say that this is my code:

```
function get(url, callback) {
  // get "responseText" using "requests"
  // extract the anchor tags href from the "responseText"
  callback({"https://url1.com": {}, "https://url2.com": {});
}

get("https://www.example.com", (urls) => {
  console.log(urls);
});
```

When you run the code the output should be:

```
{ "https://url1.com": {}, "https://url2.com": {} }
```

What I don't understand is how do I recursively go to `"https://url1.com"` then get this output:

```
{ "https://url1.com": { "https://sub-url-1.com": {} }, "https://url2.com": { "https://sub-url-2.com": {} } }
```

What if there is a depth of 5? How would I recursively loop through each sub URL 5 levels deep then get the sub URLs for it?

What is this type of recursion called and how do I implement it in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't see any attempt at recursion in your code?

Comment: @Bergi As stupid as this might make me look, I honestly don't know where to start, I don't even know what this type of recursion is called :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with `crawl`, it takes a starting url (string) and a starting depth (int) and returns a promised *result*. Our result is the type (or "shape") of our intended output. In this case, it is an object with url strings as keys and the values are either an empty object or another nested result -

```
// type url = string
// type result = (url, result) object | empty

// crawl : (string * int) -> result promise
const crawl = (initUrl = '/', initDepth = 0) =>
{ const loop = (urls, depth) =>
    parallel
      ( urls
      , u =>
          depth === 0
            ? [ u, {} ]
            : loop (get (u), depth - 1) 
                .then (r => [ u, r ])
      )
      .then (Object.fromEntries)
  return loop ([ initUrl ], initDepth)
}
```

Vertical styling is not common but helps the eye identify code elements that align on tab-stop vertical rules. Open whitespace allows for comments but they become less necessary as familiarity with the style is gained -

```
// type url = string
// type result = (url, result) object | empty

// crawl : (string * int) -> result promise
const crawl = (initUrl = '/', initDepth = 0) =>
{ const loop = (urls, depth) =>
    parallel             // parallel requests
      ( urls             // each url
      , u =>             // as u
          depth === 0                   // exit condition
            ? [ u, {} ]                 // base: [ key, value ]
            : loop (get (u), depth - 1) // inductive: smaller problem
                .then (r => [ u, r ])   //   [ key, value ]
      )
      .then (Object.fromEntries)        // convert [ key, value ]
                                        //      to { key: value }

  return loop ([ initUrl ], initDepth)  // init loop
}
```

This leverages a generic utility `parallel` which is useful for processing a promised array -

```
// parallel : (('a array) promise * 'a -> 'b) -> ('b array) promise 
const parallel = async (p, f) =>
  Promise.all ((await p) .map (x => f (x)))
```

Or if you don't want to rely on `async-await` -

```
// parallel : (('a array) promise * 'a -> 'b) -> ('b array) promise 
const parallel = (p, f) =>
  Promise.all
    ( Promise
        .resolve (p)
        .then (r => r .map (x => f (x)))
    )
```

Given a mocked `sitemap` and corresponding `get` function -

```
// sitemap : (string, string array) object
const sitemap =
  { "/": [ "/a", "/b", "/c" ]
  , "/a": [ "/a/1", "/a/11", "/a/111" ]
  , "/a/1": [ "/a/1/2", "a/1/22" ]
  , "/a/1/2": [ "/a/1/2/3" ]
  , "/a/1/2/3": [ "/a/1/2/3/4" ]
  , "/a/11": [ "/a/11/2", "a/11/22" ]
  , "/a/11/22": [ "/a/11/22/33"]
  , "/b": [ "/b/1" ]
  , "/b/1": [ "/b/1/2" ]
  }

// get : string -> (string array) promise      
const get = async (url = '') =>
  Promise
    .resolve (sitemap[url] || [] )
    .then (delay)

// delay : ('a * int) -> 'a promise
const delay = (x, ms = 250) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))
```

We can see how `crawl` responds at various depths -

```
crawl ('/') .then (console.log, console.error)
// { '/': {} }

crawl ('/', 1) .then (console.log, console.error)
// { '/': { '/a': {}, '/b': {}, '/c': {} } }

crawl ('/b', 1) .then (console.log, console.error)
// { '/b': { '/b/1': {} } }

crawl ('/b', 2) .then (console.log, console.error)
// {
//   "/b": {
//     "/b/1": {
//       "/b/1/2": {}
//     }
//   }
// }
```

Here we crawl the root `"/"` with a depth of `Infinity` -

```
crawl ("/", Infinity) .then (console.log, console.error)
// {
//   "/": {
//     "/a": {
//       "/a/1": {
//         "/a/1/2": {
//           "/a/1/2/3": {
//             "/a/1/2/3/4": {}
//           }
//         },
//         "a/1/22": {}
//       },
//       "/a/11": {
//         "/a/11/2": {},
//         "a/11/22": {}
//       },
//       "/a/111": {}
//     },
//     "/b": {
//       "/b/1": {
//         "/b/1/2": {}
//       }
//     },
//     "/c": {}
//   }
// }
```

Simply replace `get` with a real function that takes an input url and returns an array of hrefs - `crawl` will work just the same.

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const parallel = async (p, f) =>
  Promise.all ((await p) .map (x => f (x)))

const crawl = (initUrl = '/', initDepth = 0) =>
{ const loop = (urls, depth) =>
    parallel
      ( urls
      , u =>
          depth === 0
            ? [ u, {} ]
            : loop (get (u), depth - 1) 
                .then (r => [ u, r ])
      )
      .then (Object.fromEntries)
  return loop ([ initUrl ], initDepth)
}

// mock
const sitemap =
  { "/": [ "/a", "/b", "/c" ]
  , "/a": [ "/a/1", "/a/11", "/a/111" ]
  , "/a/1": [ "/a/1/2", "a/1/22" ]
  , "/a/1/2": [ "/a/1/2/3" ]
  , "/a/1/2/3": [ "/a/1/2/3/4" ]
  , "/a/11": [ "/a/11/2", "a/11/22" ]
  , "/a/11/22": [ "/a/11/22/33"]
  , "/b": [ "/b/1" ]
  , "/b/1": [ "/b/1/2" ]
  }
  
const get = async (url = '') =>
  Promise
    .resolve (sitemap[url] || [] )
    .then (delay)

const delay = (x, ms = 250) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))

// demos
crawl ('/') .then (console.log, console.error)
// { '/': {} }

crawl ('/', 1) .then (console.log, console.error)
// { '/': { '/a': {}, '/b': {}, '/c': {} } }

crawl ('/b', 1) .then (console.log, console.error)
// { '/b': { '/b/1': {} } }

crawl ('/b', 2) .then (console.log, console.error)
// {
//   "/b": {
//     "/b/1": {
//       "/b/1/2": {}
//     }
//   }
// }

crawl ("/", Infinity) .then (console.log, console.error)
// {
//   "/": {
//     "/a": {
//       "/a/1": {
//         "/a/1/2": {
//           "/a/1/2/3": {
//             "/a/1/2/3/4": {}
//           }
//         },
//         "a/1/22": {}
//       },
//       "/a/11": {
//         "/a/11/2": {},
//         "a/11/22": {}
//       },
//       "/a/111": {}
//     },
//     "/b": {
//       "/b/1": {
//         "/b/1/2": {}
//       }
//     },
//     "/c": {}
//   }
// }
```

Comment: It would be neat if duplicate links created cyclical references within the object. I might write an answer that does that...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts this is a good recommendation. `Map` could be used as a sort of cache. If a url has already been cached, we can grab the corresponding object from the cache. Feel free to copy any code here to use as a starting point, if you wish.

Comment: I'm not really as comfortable with FP as you seem to be, so it wouldn't feel natural to expand on your answer. However I had the same idea using `Map` as a cache so I'll definitely include that.

Comment: Apologies for the late accept, thanks for the answer, I appreciate the effort.